# Shinyproxy: Message: Container did not respond in time (500)

Tags: r, docker, shiny, containers, shinyproxy

after building an rShiny app, I would like to host it online on my own server.

I currently have a server with Ubuntu (latest version), on which I would like to run the hosting with the help of Docker, Shinyproxy and nginx.

I have already created the Docker image and successfully executed it with the help of "sudo docker run...." - everything works fine here. Unfortunately, hosting via ShinyProxy does not work. So the error must be (I think) my ShinyProxy file (application.yml) or nginx (default, default).

When I call up the URL, I get the following error message: (See the full log at the end of the question)

> Error
> Status code: 500
> Message: Container did not respond in time

My ShinyApp classically consists of the following components: Funktionen.R, Inputs.R, install_packages.R, Server.R, ui.R

I tried to check all ports, the settings and everything, but it does not work.

I hope you find everything you need to analyse the error below and hopefully find a solution! Thank you very much!

Let me know if u need more information!

---

### Code:

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM rocker/r-base:latest
LABEL maintainer="USER <user@example.com>"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev\
    xvfb\
    xauth\
    xfonts-base\
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libmagick++-dev\
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN install.r shiny
RUN echo "local(options(shiny.port = 3838, shiny.host = '0.0.0.0'))" > /usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site
RUN addgroup --system app \
    && adduser --system --ingroup app app
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY app .
RUN Rscript install_packages.R
RUN chown app:app -R /home/app
USER app
EXPOSE 3838
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/home/app')"]
```

My application.yml (Shinyproxy) looks like this:

```
proxy:
  title: ShinyProxy
#  logo-url: https://link/to/your/logo.png
  landing-page: /
  favicon-path: favicon.ico
  heartbeat-rate: 10000
  heartbeat-timeout: 600000
  port: 8080
  container-wait-time: 60000
  admin-groups: admins
  hide-navbar: true
  # Docker configuration
  docker:
    cert-path: /home/none
    url: http://localhost:2375
    port-range-start: 20000
  specs:
  - id: 01_hello
    display-name: Hello Shiny App
    description: A simple reactive histogram
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/app')"]
    container-image: DOCKERIMAGE:latest
    logo-url: https://github.com/analythium/shinyproxy-1-click/raw/master/digitalocean/images/app-hist.png
    access-groups: [admins, users]
  

logging:
  file:
    shinyproxy.log

spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 200MB
      max-request-size: 200MB
```

And my nginx default files (sites enabled, sites available) looks like this:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name URL.de www.URL.de;
    location / {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 6000s;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
}
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/URL.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/URL.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.URL.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    if ($host = URL.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name URL.de www.URL.de;
    return 404;
}
```

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name URL.de www.URL.de;
    location / {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 6000s;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
}
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/URL.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/URL.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.URL.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 
    if ($host = URL.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name URL.de www.URL.de;
    return 404; 
}
```

The entire error-log looks like this:

```
Error
Status code: 500

Message: Container did not respond in time

Stack Trace:
eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.ContainerProxyException: Container did not respond in time
at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.AbstractContainerBackend.startProxy(AbstractContainerBackend.java:143)
at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.service.ProxyService.startProxy(ProxyService.java:226)
at eu.openanalytics.shinyproxy.controllers.AppController.getOrStart(AppController.java:106)
at eu.openanalytics.shinyproxy.controllers.AppController.startApp(AppController.java:63)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:517)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:91)
at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.util.ProxyMappingManager$ProxyPathHandler.handleRequest(ProxyMappingManager.java:160)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:370)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:836)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1449)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```